# Button inside template of another button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates, button

I've created a button template that looks like a tile:

[image]

When the user clicks the tile, it expands like so:

[image]

The problem is, when the user clicks a button inside the tile, the click handler for the tile button is triggered as well as the handler for the button inside the template.

A super simple example is:

XAML:

```
<Button Click="Outer_Click">
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Outer"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <Button Click="Inner_Click"
            Content="Inner" />
  </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

C#:

```
private void Outer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  MessageBox.Show("Outer!");
}

private void Inner_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  MessageBox.Show("Inner!");
}
```

Is there any way to not handle the "outer" click event if the user has clicked the "inner" button?

Comment: You could use `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` instead of `Click` and then set `e.Handled = true;`

Comment: Simply handle the click where it first occurs and do not let it propagate upside VisualTree. To sum up in your inner handler when you done showing the message "Inner!" just set e.Handled = true. Thats it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using comments left by HighCore and dev hedgehog, this solved my problem:

```
private void Inner_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  MessageBox.Show("Inner!");
  e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: In my case when i click the button in the foreground it fires first the code of the button on the background. How do i turn this around?