# how wpf binding a event in ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf

Code behind:

```
 public class LoginButton : Button
    {
        public static DependencyProperty LoginedProperty;
        public static DependencyProperty LoginEventProperty;
        public delegate void LoginEventDelegate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e);
        static LoginButton()
        {
            LoginedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Logined", typeof(Boolean), typeof(LoginButton));
            LoginEventProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("LoginEvent", typeof(LoginEventDelegate), typeof(LoginButton));
        }

        public Boolean Logined
        {
            get { return (Boolean)base.GetValue(LoginedProperty); }
            set { base.SetValue(LoginedProperty, value); }
        }

        public event LoginEventDelegate LoginEvent;
        protected virtual void OnLoginEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (LoginEvent != null)
                LoginEvent(sender,e);
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="LoginButtonTemplate" TargetType="local:LoginButton">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0"></ContentPresenter>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,0,0">
                        <Label Name="L" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="0" Foreground="#919191" Visibility="Collapsed">logined</Label>
                        <Button Name="B" Template="{StaticResource CustomButton}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0" Foreground="#3598db" Content="click login"></Button>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Logined" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="L" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                        <Setter TargetName="B" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
```

--------------------------------
I want to achieve this function:
The button which Name="B" in ControlTemplate,when I click it,it work the custom event OnLoginEvent?
How can i do it?
--------------------------------
Oh,it seems no one knows my meaning for my poor English.
Now I explain the function for more detailed.
The software needs to manage about 100 or more account,if the account is not logined,it will show the button let user to login.And if is logined it will show the label that is logined
So I make a new Custom usercontrol named LoginButton,and create a boolean 'Logined' to control button if is logined.
Beaucase of different account has different login function.So I create a new event 'LoginEvent' to apply different login function.Now the question is the button Name="B" which to login.I need binding the button Name="B" click event or previewmousedown event to the event 'LoginEvent'.But I can't find the way to binding it.
Please help me,thanks a lot.

Comment: As I see you want create button inside another button.. There is problem with event propagation, you need use PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event for handle click on inner button. How to do it you can read in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19668935/button-inside-template-of-another-button. <Button Name="B" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="YourHandler"/>

Comment: Handle the click event of your `Button : B` and raise the event from there in your `Custom Control`. Or, replace `Button : B` with a new `Custom Button` and that `Button` would be raising any event of your choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could override the `OnApplyTemplate` method of the `LoginButton` class and hook up an event handler to the click event for the "B" button in the template that raises the event.

`LoginEvent` should be an event and not a dependency property though.

Try this:

```
public class LoginButton : Button
{
    public static DependencyProperty LoginedProperty;
    public delegate void LoginEventDelegate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e);

    static LoginButton()
    {
        LoginedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Logined", typeof(Boolean), typeof(LoginButton));
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        Button b = this.Template.FindName("B", this) as Button;
        if(b != null)
        {
            b.Click += (s, e) => OnLoginEvent(s, e);
        }
    }

    public Boolean Logined
    {
        get { return (Boolean)base.GetValue(LoginedProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(LoginedProperty, value); }
    }

    public event LoginEventDelegate LoginEvent;
    protected virtual void OnLoginEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (LoginEvent != null)
            LoginEvent(sender, e);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<local:LoginButton Template="{StaticResource LoginButtonTemplate}" LoginEvent="LoginButton_LoginEvent"/>
```

---

```
private void LoginButton_LoginEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Login!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much my god!It works!Whereas I wanna ask one more question.Your example use Code Behind to bind it.If it has another way that use xaml to bind it?

Comment: No, you cannot define an event handler in XAML.

Comment: Thanks sir,I am very sorry about my poor programming capacity.Thank God&you to help me.